# Review count per product

Tags: comments

I want to get the amount of reviews of a certain woocommerce product. I have this code but it gives me the total amount of reviews (so only the amount of reviews of that specific product).

```
function get_total_reviews_count(){
    return get_comments(array(
        'post_ID' =>'12345',
    'status'   => 'approve',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'count' => true
    ));
}
add_shortcode('reviews_count', 'get_total_reviews_count');
```

Hope you guys can help me adjust the code so that I will only see the amount of reviews of product 12345.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce provides [a function](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_review_count) for this. You should not need to query the comments and count them:

```
add_shortcode(
    'reviews_count',
    function() {
        // Make sure we're on a Product.
        if ( function_exists( 'is_product' ) && is_product() ) {
            // Get a WC_Product object for the current product.
            $product = wc_get_product( get_queried_object_id() );
            // Return the review count.
            return $product->get_review_count();
        }
    }
);
```

If you want to display the reviews count for a specific product you can use:

```
add_shortcode(
    'reviews_count',
    function() {
        if ( function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ) {
            // Get a WC_Product object for the product.
            $product = wc_get_product( 12345 );
            // Return the review count.
            return $product->get_review_count();
        }
    }
);
```

If you want to be able to pass the product ID to the shortcode (like this: `[reviews_count id="12345"]`), you can use:

```
add_shortcode(
    'reviews_count',
    function( $atts ) {
        // Make sure an ID was passed,
        if ( ! empty( $atts['id'] && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ) {
            // Get a WC_Product object for the product.
            $product = wc_get_product( (int) $atts['id'] );
            // Return the review count.
            return $product->get_review_count();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your answer, I want to place this counter on a regular page. So I need to tell somewhere that this is about product 12345. Where should I do this or will the code be different then? Thanks! Right now I use the following adjusted code and this seems to work (but maybe it can be better coded?) function get_total_reviews_count(){
    return get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => '25374',
        'status' => 'approve',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));
}
add_shortcode('reviews_count', 'get_total_reviews_count');

Comment: I updated my answer with two options. Don't use `get_comments()`.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thank you so much for your help. The third and last code sounds like a perfect solution, this way I can use 1 code for multiple products. The only problem is that when I place the code in my functions.php my site goes down. Can you have a second look at the code because when we'll be able to get this working that would be terrific. Thanks!